# Как к определенной дате добавить X дней?

Tags: php, datetime

Имею дату в таком формате 2023.02.06 как к ней добавить например 5 дней?
Пробовал так `date( '2023.02.06', strtotime("+5 days"))` но не работает, чувствую что то делаю не так.

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос так, может кому пригодится.

```
$myDateValid = '2023-02-06';
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($myDateValid.'+ 5 days'));
```